# Navigation Scrolling and Clicking anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using these two Scripts, one is for changing class when anchor tag is clicked and the other is changing class when scroll down the page. When I click the anchor tag, the class changes but because of scroll function,it reverts backs, I am also animating to my scroll page. How can I avoid the clashes amongst the two.

Change class based on anchor.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.sidebar-nav li a').click(function(e) { 
$('.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('active_nav');
var $parent = $(this).parent();
if (!$parent.hasClass('active_nav')) {
$parent.addClass('active_nav');
}
e.preventDefault();});});   
</script>
```

Change class based on scrolling

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.page').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll) {
            $('.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('active_nav');
            $('.sidebar-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active_nav');
        }
    });});  
</script>
```

Scrolling to the page

```
<script>
$('.scroll a').click(function(e) {
var goTo = $(this).attr('href'); // selects element that was clicked
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$(goTo).offset().top}, 1000);
e.preventDefault();
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add a condition if `$(this).position().top + $(this).height() > windscroll`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.page').each(function(i) {
    var posTop = $(this).position().top, 
        h = $(this).height();

    if (posTop  <= windscroll && posTop + h > windscroll ) {
        $('.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('active_nav');
        $('.sidebar-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active_nav');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: While scrolling, the classes on list elements do not change

Comment: ah yes you need to execute this on `$(window).scroll();`. I've updated the answer and I made a simple demo on jsfiddle. [**jsfiddle.net/d23bW/**](http://jsfiddle.net/d23bW/1/). I also think there's no need to change the class on anchor click as you are already doing it on scroll.

Comment: Yup ! works awesome. I removed the script for anchor links as well. I just need this to work .. Thank you :)